# filter api index action using the ID in the URI pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Question how can i filter my get api function using the ID ni my URI pattern
for example if the client side uses the localhost:3000/users/1/projects
he will get the projects with a field of "user_id" equal to the URI pattern /users/:id

#routes
   resources :users do
      resourcers :projects
   end

```
#project controller
def index
@projects = Project.all
render json: @projects
end
 #users assocciation
 has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

#project association
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :task, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
end

#DB schema
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.text     "descriptions"
t.date     "startDate"
t.date     "dueDate"
t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.boolean  "project_confirmation"
```

end

what we want is when the client side uses this route  /users/:user_id/projects(.:format)  he accepts projects with field of user_id similar to the routes /users/:id

Answer (score 0):

Use AMS or Jbuilder for that.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder